# what does the value of fitness function means

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, evaluation

I want to ask about the meaning of fitness value for any fitness function. In other words, if the fitness value, for example, is 1.5 what does this value means? how this value relate the current solution to the optimal solution?

Comment: The exact meaning depends on what exact implementation of fitness function was used. The scores are relative though. If higher scores are better, 4 is better than 2. The value itself doesn't necessarily have a useful meaning.

Comment: if the value itself doesn't have a useful meaning how to know how the solution relative to the optimal solution in percentage ?

Comment: That's hard, and again, you'd have to know the specifics of the fitness function being used. Genetic Algorithms are *not* guaranteed or even well suited to giving you the best solution though. They are better are searching large search spaces for possible close solutions. They are prone to getting stuck at local maximums.

Comment: the fitness value is relative, depending on the range and type. For example, a genetic program trying to emulate a picture of 256x256, where the higher the fitness value, the better it is, and the highest value being 65536 (100% emulation), but in a case of Travelling Salesmen Problem, the distance can be used as a fitness value, and obviously the lower the distance(fitness value), the better it is with the lowest value being the best answer.